# Syncfusion Xamarin 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream' during adding image

Tags: image, pdf, xamarin, stream, syncfusion

I would like to load image to pdf from stream. When I try to do that I get an error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream'
```

Here is my code

```
Stream imageStream = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Resources.drawable.image.png");
            
PdfImage image = PdfImage.FromStream(imageStream);   <---- here is error

g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(20, 20));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly , in this way you need to put the image in Forms project instead of Android project .In my demo I put the image in the folder **Assets** . And the code should like the following

[image]

```
var assembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Assets.icon.png");
```

In addition , make sure that the build action of the image is **Embeddded Resource**

Right Click the image -> Properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the issue with loading the image to pdf from stream, but it is working properly. And the images are loaded and insert into the Pdf document and make sure that the build action of the image is Embeddded Resource. Kindly please try the sample in this below documentation and let us know the result.

**KB** : https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10375/how-to-insert-an-image-into-pdf-in-xamarin

**UG** : https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-images

**Note**: I am work for Syncfusion.